# Postfix won't start cause port 25 is busy by sendmail, can't uninstall sendmail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

Something weird:

I get this error sending an email:

```
fatal: bind 127.0.0.1 port 25: Address already in use
```

So I check and sendmail is running:

```
sudo netstat -lnp |grep :25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18968/sendmail: MTA
```

But can't uninstall:

```
apt-get remove sendmail
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'sendmail' is not installed, so not removed
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you installed `sendmail` with `apt-get`?

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail was uninstalled while you have installed Postfix.

You must kill sendmail with `kill 18968`

Answer (score 0):

The package name for sendmail may not actually be `sendmail`.  Try verifying how you got sendmail (which package installed it).

Running `which sendmail` will provide you the full path of sendmail which you can then plug into `dpkg -S` to find the package that provides it.

Example:

```
$ which sendmail
/sbin/sendmail
$ dpkg -S /sbin/sendmail
sendmail: /sbin/sendmail
```

Please note, I don't have a Debian based system available to me so the command outputs are just educated guesses, but the idea is the same.

From there, you can uninstall the appropriate package if you so desire.  That being said, it might just be worth it to stop and disable the sendmail service, that will vary by distro/version but should be easy enough to figure out.